# Custom Permissions in Android M, after and before

Tags: android, permissions

- Is is a good practice to define Custom permission in both or multiple applications, as one can not control which application will be installed first. (It works, already tested)
- Can custom permission be somehow treated as a run-time permission on Android M and above devices.

Comment: "Is is a good practice to define Custom permission in both or multiple applications, as one can not control which application will be installed first. (It works, already tested)" -- IMHO, not prior to Android 5.0, and then only if you are the developer of all the apps and can sign them with the same signing key.